# redirect https://domain to https://www.domain in httpd24

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, redhat

I'm trying to redirect URL responses from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com in the apache24 configuration, I'm using Redhat Server.

I have tried to create this Rewrite Condition but its not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not working HOW? doesn't redirect? redirects to the wrong place?

Comment: its not redirect me to the https:// www domain com its only showing https://domain.com

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: no this is the only one running

Comment: Do you have the `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /` directives above these rewrite rules?

Comment: I have RewriteEngine On but now RewriteBase / , If you can let me know how to add RewriteBase / in my apache configuration I would be thankful to you

Comment: You can write `RewriteBase /` directly below where you have the `RewriteEngine On` diretcive declared.  Take a look at the example here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the Issue by using Directive IF Condition powered by Apache2.4

I have added this code to my ssl.conf file where it redirected all requests sent to **https:// domain .com** to **https:// www .domain .com** . Add this code before the  Tag :

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.domain.com'">
Redirect "/" "https://www.domain.com/"
</If>
```

Thank you all for your comments and trying to fix my issue, really its something I appreciate it. Please take a look @ for more information about httpd24 directives https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html

Comment: Good Question & Answer

Answer (score 0):

() is a capturing group. You don't want that when you check `HTTP_HOST` unless you're going to use it as part of the new URL. Also make sure to add the `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) on your `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You can test your htaccess here http://htaccess.mwl.be/ without having to upload and refresh your site.

Comment: I have tried it but still the same, thank you I got your point about the ^ and $ for the RewriteRule , but it still the same not directing to http:// www .domain .com

Comment: Yes, and tried it from another machine to make sure that's a not browser cache issue. I'm writing these conditions for my apache 2.4 running on Redhat server.

Comment: I'm not sure. Something else is going on. Can you access https on your site by typing a url in the browser? Does it redirect to http? I've tested the answer provided and it redirects without a problem.

Comment: when I access any https://domain page its working under the url of https://domain and when I type the https://www.domain its working fine, so I think my SSL is working fine